# Wrong calculation error by python3

Tags: python-3.x

I was stuck with a case where python3 gave me the answer of

```
int(226553150*1023473145/5)
```

to be

```
46374212988031352
```

even though the answer to this should be

```
46374212988031350
```

Please help me with what is going wrong and how do I fix it. Thanks.

Comment: If you use truncating division (avoiding `float`s), you get the right answer:  `226553150*1023473145//5  ==  46374212988031350`

Comment: note: `3//2=1` vs `3/2=1.5`.

Comment: If you're looking for a more general answer, the [`decimal`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html) module may be what you're looking for